# Which iPhone Framework defines NSPersistentDocument?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've been working on an iPhone app which uses `CoreData` and I would like to use `NSPersistentDocument` if I can.  I keep seeing discussions about using `NSPersistentDocument` in iPhone apps but no mention of which iPhone Framework defines `NSPersistentDocument`?

Answer (score 5):

`NSPersistentDocument` is only available for Mac OS X. It's not available in iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the AppKit Framework.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPersistentDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Note that AppKit is not available on the iPhone.